# array filter with lodash for react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filter, lodash

I have an array object that look like this:

```
[{
        sellerId: "seller1",
        name: "Nike",
        item: [{
                id: "xxx1"
                isChecked: false
                price: "719700.00"
                productName: "product a"
                quantity: 2
            },
            {
                id: "xxx2"
                isChecked: true
                price: "219700.00"
                productName: "product b"
                quantity: 1

            }
        ],
    },
    {
        sellerId: "seller2",
        name: "Adidas",
        item: [{
                id: "xxx1"
                isChecked: false
                price: "49700.00"
                productName: "product x"
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                id: "xxx2"
                isChecked: true
                price: "4700.00"
                productName: "product y"
                quantity: 5

            }
        ],
    },
]
```

now I want to convert or filter my data by **isChecked = true** on object called Item, so it will look like this:

```
[{
        sellerId: "seller1",
        name: "Nike",
        item: [
            {
                id: "xxx2"
                isChecked: true
                price: "219700.00"
                productName: "product b"
                quantity: 1

            }
        ],
    },
    {
        sellerId: "seller2",
        name: "Adidas",
        item: [
            {
                id: "xxx2"
                isChecked: true
                price: "4700.00"
                productName: "product y"
                quantity: 5

            }
        ],
    },
]
```

**EDITED:**

And then IF there is NO isChecked: true in one seller, it will not display the seller data, for example if there is no isChecked on Adidas seller, i expected the object will look like this:

```
[{
        sellerId: "seller1",
        name: "Nike",
        item: [
            {
                id: "xxx2"
                isChecked: true
                price: "219700.00"
                productName: "product b"
                quantity: 1

            }
        ],
    },
]
```

I have try using lodash like this, but it still not remove the item that have isChecked: false

`_.filter(data, { item: [{ isChecked: false }] })`

Any help on how I can do that with lodash or simple javascript filter()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **filter** and **map** functions:

```
sellers = data.map((d) => {return {...d, item: d.item.filter(i=>i.isChecked)}})
```

For empty items you can filter it again like this:

```
filterd_seller = sellers.filter(seller => seller.item.length)
```

Or a better answer you can use **reduce**:

```
data.reduce((filtered, seller) => {
  const item = seller.item.filter(i => i.isChecked);
  if (item.length) {
     filtered.push({...seller, item });
  }
  return filtered;
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi Elham, it works, but you type it wrong, ...d should be in the first line after return..
anyway, one more thing, IF there is NO isChecked: true on Adidas seller for example, it only return data from Nike, how can i do that?

Comment: I edit my answer for your second question

Answer (score 0):

Map the array of objects (using lodash or vanilla), and then recreated the object while filtering out any item with `isChecked: false` :

```js
const arr = [{"sellerId":"seller1","name":"Nike","item":[{"id":"xxx1","isChecked":false,"price":"719700.00","productName":"product a","quantity":2},{"id":"xxx2","isChecked":true,"price":"219700.00","productName":"product b","quantity":1}]},{"sellerId":"seller2","name":"Adidas","item":[{"id":"xxx1","isChecked":false,"price":"49700.00","productName":"product x","quantity":1},{"id":"xxx2","isChecked":true,"price":"4700.00","productName":"product y","quantity":5}]}]

const result = arr.map(({ item, ...o }) => ({
  ...o,
  item: item.filter(o => o.isChecked)
}))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```